# proof of limit using delta-epsilon definition

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Let $h=f+g$ with $f,\,g$ functions of domain $\Bbb R$. Prove if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\in\Bbb R$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=\infty$. Use the definition of limit, without limit laws or other theoems.

Could anyone share me an insight how to approach this question? and possibly how to prove this with proper format?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you remember the formal definitions involved in your question?

Comment: In my rough work, I am trying to choose the value of k such that when x>k, I can show that h(x) > M. But I am stuck on which value of k I should choose.

Answer (score 5):

Given any number $M>0$, we have to show that there exists $a>0$, such that $h(x)>M$ for all $x>a$.

Now as $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=L\in\Bbb R$, there exists $A$ such that $g(x)\in(L-1,L+1)$ for all $x\ge A$.

Also since $f(x)$ diverges to $\infty$ for $x\to\infty$, there exists $B$ such that $f(x)\ge M-L+1$ for all $x\ge B$.

Take $a=\max\{A,B\}$. Then for all $x\ge a$, $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)\ge (M-L+1)+(L-1)=M$.

Comment: can you elaborate how the fact g(x) has a limit as x goes to infinity implies there exists A such that g(x) is in the interval (L-1, L+1)?

Comment: @ext-vayne It's the $\varepsilon=1$ special case of the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Love you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Simply write down the definition of the limits for $f$ and $g$. They both give you a lower bound on $f$ and $g$, and by a mere addition you get alower bound on $f+g$.

> $$\forall M:\exists N':\forall x>N':f(x)>M\\\forall\epsilon:\exists N'':\forall x>N'':g(x)>G-\epsilon.$$ Then take $\epsilon=\dfrac1M$ and $N'''=\max(N',N'')$ and you get $$\forall M:\exists N''':\forall x>N''':f(x)+g(x)>M+G-\frac1M.$$